# Connect a point shape to image contained in a folder

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector

I use QGIS.
I have a point shape with many points on the map (like 10-20...).
Each one is a surveyed flora's species on field, by "locus-gis" android app, taking also a photo directly on the app.
Does is possible to connect the two data's informations in the same way (or other way) in QGIS on my computer?

My objective is to having a way like clicking on one point and see information and the related picture.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to relate your photos with the points?

Comment: Yes...one point-one photo

Comment: Yes, it is possible in QGIS. You also can use QField to make your photo in the field and automatically add it to a point on the map.

Comment: Maybe you can use [Import geotagged photos](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#qgisimportphotos)

Comment: About capturing photos in QField https://www.opengis.ch/2023/04/04/capturing-more-while-in-the-field-with-the-new-qfield-2-7/

Comment: Since version 3.30 QGIS supports multimedia attachments (photo, audio, video) in the attribute table https://www.qgis.org/ru/site/forusers/visualchangelog330/index.html#feature-audiovisual-multimedia-attribute-attachments-support